# Confusing Fibonacci number program

Tags: c++, recursion, fibonacci

Ok so I am having trouble understanding exactly how this program works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getFibNumber(int fibIndex)
{
    if(fibIndex < 2)
        return fibIndex;
    else
        return getFibNumber(fibIndex - 1) + getFibNumber(fibIndex - 2);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "Enter 0-based index of desired Fibonacci number: ";
    int index = 0;
    cin >> index;

    cout << "Fibonacci number is: " << getFibNumber(index) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Specifically, what does "getFibNumber(...)" do when it reiterates(if that is the correct word)? I can't figure out what it does if the integer "fibIndex" that is passed in is greater than or equal to 2. Sorry to ask such a basic question, but I am really stumped by this and I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: This is called Recursion. Just look at the related questions or google it.

Comment: Right, and I've seen and used recursion before, but this... I don't understand what the "return getFibNumber(fibIndex - 1) + getFibNumber(fibIndex - 2);" does, because it seems like you could just do "return (fibIndex - 1) + (fibIndex - 2);"

Comment: @JTadeo28 That's different from calling the function again, twice. The idea is that it eventually just returns fibIndex, adds that with the result of the other function calls and eventually returns.

Comment: @JTadeo28 - the best way to learn is to actually run the program with what seems right to you and see what you get (or better yet - debug it to see what you get on each step). This will take less time and will be infinitely more useful than reading explanations. In addition, the internet and SO are full with examples and explanations of this issue.

Comment: Another good technique is to get a piece of paper and draw a diagram of what happens for `getFibNumber(5)` or so. Creating that graph can help you "see" it better than stepping through it in a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone mentioned here, this is basically recursion.

Just to get a feel of how this program works, I have made the recursion tree with initial `fibIndex` as `5`.

```
           5                   5 calls 4 and 3.
       /      \                
      4        3               4 calls 3 and 2. 3 calls 2 and 1.
    /   \     /  \
   3     2    2   1            1 is base case, returns 1.
  / \   / \  / \  
 2   1 1  0 1  0               2 is not base case. So calls 1 and 0.
/ \
1  0
```

Comment: Nice diagram. Worth noting that 1) `0, 1, 2` is *not* part of the actual Fibonacci sequence, and 2) this has exponential complexity whereas the minimum complexity of finding a given Fibonacci number is only proportional to the number of digits in it.

Comment: As for #1, I did what OP wanted. For #2, I don't think OP will be able to understand dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2):

This is called recursion. Instead of doing this with a loop it calls the function again, but with a different parameter. Eventually, the base condition will be true, and the function will return, causing the rest of the calls to return also. This can be a very powerful tool in the right situation.